# Query on $X_n\rightarrow 1 \ \text{in probability}$

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, proof-verification

> Consider a sample of $n$ points randomly placed on a circle of radius $1$. It
>   can be shown that $X_n$ , the distance from the centre of the circle of the
>   farthest point, has density function
>   $$f_{X_n}(x)=2nx^{2n-1} \ \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<1$$
>   Show that $$X_n\rightarrow 1 \ \text{in probability}$$

My attempt:

I first calculated that $$F_{X_n}(x)=1 \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<1$$
Now, I want to show that $$\forall\epsilon>0, \ \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(\left|X_n-1\right|>\epsilon)=0$$
My question is, how do I deal with the absolute value $\left|X_n-1\right|$?
For instance, if I assumed it was positive, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(\left|X_n-1\right|>\epsilon)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n>\epsilon+1)=0$$
As $$\mathbb{P}\left(X_n>\frac{1}{2}\right)=1-F_{X_n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=1-1=0$$

But why is it okay to make this assumption?

Comment: On a **disk** (instead of circle) you probably mean.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure. The question is literally copied and pasted from a final exam paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $X_n \leq 1$ almost surely. (Because the density is $0$ for $x>1$). Hence $|X_n-1|>\epsilon $ iff $X_n <1-\epsilon $. Thus $P\{|X_n-1|>\epsilon\} =\int_0^{1-\epsilon } 2nx^{2n-1} \, dx =(1-\epsilon )^{2n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty $.

Comment: I don't see how as $n\rightarrow\infty, \ \ (1-\epsilon)^{2n}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: For any number $x \in (0,1)$ we have $x^{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty $. Take $x=1-\epsilon $.